# How to format cards made with jinja for loop using css

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I am making a recipe search website where I use jinja to create cards for the search result, where each card contains a recipe. I have been unable to place the cards correctly, currently the cards all appear in a vertical line. I want to make the cards appear in rows where each row has two cards.
This is my current html:

```
<div class="cards">
    {% for i in range(results['hits']|length) %}
    <div class="card" id="{{ i }}">
        <img class="food_img" src="{{ results['hits'][i]['recipe']['image'] }}" alt="Recipe Img" style="width:100%;" >
        <div class="container">
          <a href="{{ results['hits'][i]['recipe']['url'] }}" target="_blank"><b>{{ results['hits'][i]['recipe']['label'] }}</b></a>
            <a class="fa fa-plus" href="{{ url_for('save', index=i) }}"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

I've tried using various css including display: flex, margin: auto, and position. I've also tried using a second for loop in the html that adds a  every two cards. Here is my css:

```
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: .3125em;
    width: 18.75em;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom:  0.9375em;
    background-color: white;
}
  
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 .5em 1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
  
.container {
    padding:  0.125em 1em;   
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3125em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3.125em;
}

img {
    border-radius: 0.3125em 0.3125em 0 0;
}

.cards {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```